# Spring Boot @RequestBody does not copy parameters fully

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, request-mapping

I have a JSON object that I pass to an API endpoint:

```
{
    "ID": 12312,
    "location": "London",
    "friends": 1231,
    "Name": "dsd",
    "verified": true

}
```

I have an endpoint `UserController`:

```
@PostMapping("saveUser")
public String Save(@RequestBody(required = true) User newUser){
    //TODO: User needs to have ID and all other necessary params
    //TODO: RequestBody is not working. Why not?

    userservice.saveNewUser(newUser);
    return "True";
}
```

and I have a `User` class:

```
@NodeEntity
public class User {

    @Id
    private long ID;
    private String Name;
    private String location;
    private int friends;
    private boolean verified;
    private int followers; 
    .... getters and setters
```

My problem: when I insert a user, the database registers the correct friends and location filed, but the ID and followers field and name are incorrect. Does anyone know why?[image: wrong parameters parsed]

Comment: There are no `followers` in the json, so why should it contain anything? Make sure you have a `setID` method to match the `ID` in the JSON.

Comment: Only thing that is coming to my mind is that since field naming is with capital letters there is something that is messed up with reflection when conversion from json to POJO is done. Also you have 2 id fields, usually when saving object you should let db decide on the id.

Comment: Seems there is a different unique identifier for the records in DB; For the example shown `<id>` is 20 and `ID` is 0. The model class define `ID` with `@Id` annotation

Comment: @MladenSavić i think this may be the case, I changed the name to id and it set the correct fields, although without specifying I have now got <id> and id both as fields

Comment: despite not setting any constraints on the graph database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

camelCase. Try changing ID to id and Name to name. Frameworks assumes getID would have been declared as iD.

Comment: i think this is what caused it

Answer (score 1):

in general , its always better to stick to the conventions. 
if both your json , and you java code were camelCase , you shouldn't have to mess with framework specific config. 
Avoid unnecessary configuration when ever possible.

Answer (score 0):

Name and ID both have upper case first character, maybe a getter is not able to access the value. Could you try this?

```
  @Id
  @Column(name = "ID")
  private int id;

  @Column(name = "Name")
  private String name;
```

And double check getters are "getId()" and "getName()"

Comment: thank you, I changed the ID column and it seems to be working without pointing with annotations

Answer (score 0):

`@JsonProperty("ID"); private long ID;`

use the @JsonProperty to tell the mapper object the property of the request body object to read from and the response body.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/32414993)

Comment: @AbhinandanPratap Please pay attention when reviewing answers. This is not a "link-only answer", there is no link to be seen.

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.